# yii2 updateallcounter with 2 conditions

Tags: activerecord, yii2

The query would be `update table1 set id=id+1 where id>=10 and staff_id=$staff_id`.

With only single condition I can write

`\common\models\leave\table1::updateAllCounters(['id' => 1], ['>', 'id', 10]);`

How to add the where `staff_id=$staff_id?` Tried `\common\models\leave\table1::updateAllCounters(['id' => 1], ['>', 'id', 10],['staff_id'=>$staff_id]);` but no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create conditions like below

```
$condition = ['and',
    ['>', 'id', 10],
    ['=', 'staff_id',$staff_id],
];
```

and update your query

```
\common\models\leave\table1::updateAllCounters(['id' => 1],$condition);
```